# Spark combining three RDD object

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I am trying to use the result from Spark decision tree model with the BikeSharing Dataset, and I want a result outcome in form of [(Date,Actual Value, Prediction Value)].

but the outcome I get is [(Date,(Actual Value, Prediction Value))] with the below code. How can I get desired form of output? Thank you!

```
raw_data = sc.textFile(filename)
records = raw_data.map(lambda x: x.split(","))
records.cache()
data_dt = records.map(lambda r: LabeledPoint(extract_label(r), extract_features_dt(r)))
dt_model = DecisionTree.trainRegressor(data_dt, {})
preds = dt_model.predict(data_dt.map(lambda p: p.features))
actual = records.map(lambda p: extract_label(p))
true_vs_predicted_dt = actual.zip(preds)
date = records.map(lambda x: x[1])
true_vs_predicted_dt = date.zip(true_vs_predicted_dt)
true_vs_predicted_dt.take(5)
```

[(u'2011-07-12', (36.786290322580648, 22.0)), (u'2011-07-12', (36.786290322580648, 14.0)), (u'2011-07-12', (36.786290322580648, 9.0)), (u'2011-07-12', (36.786290322580648, 8.0)), (u'2011-07-12', (36.786290322580648, 6.0))]

Answer (score 0):

The inner Tuple is created from true_vs_predicted_dt = actual.zip(preds). The `zip` function will result with list of tuple.

If you want to keep the current structure you can map the Tuple2 to Tuple3

Untested code (Scala - can be easily translated to Python):

```
val tmp = true_vs_predicted_dt.map(item => (item._1, item._2._1, item._2._2))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, I tried your solution with this code

       tmp=date.map(lambda x:(x,actual,preds))

But I got error message below, please help.
Exception: It appears that you are attempting to broadcast an RDD or reference an RDD from an action or transformation. RDD transformations and actions can only be invoked by the driver, not inside of other transformations; for example, rdd1.map(lambda x: rdd2.values.count() * x) is invalid because the values transformation and count action cannot be performed inside of the rdd1.map transformation.